# How do I hold all updates related to nvidia 346.72 driver?

Tags: drivers, nvidia

Recently had to reinstall my system because of an update to the nvidia driver preventing the system from booting. I don't want to have to start all over again every time the nvidia driver updates.

I am unsure how to hold the drivers from update and to find out the name of every item I need to hold to prevent a re occurrence.

Any full instructions would be greatly appreciated.

Kind regards

Andrew

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prevent updating of a specific package?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/18654/how-to-prevent-updating-of-a-specific-package)

Answer (score 12):

**TL;DR** Use this command:

```
sudo apt-mark hold nvidia-346
```

Example:

```
% sudo apt-mark hold nvidia-346  
nvidia-346 set on hold.
```

---

And the `unhold`:

```
sudo apt-mark unhold nvidia-346
```

Example:

```
% sudo apt-mark unhold nvidia-346
Canceled hold on nvidia-346.
```

---

From `man apt-mark`

```
hold
   hold is used to mark a package as held back, which will prevent the package from being automatically installed, upgraded or removed. The command is only a wrapper around dpkg --set-selections and the state is
   therefore maintained by dpkg(1) and not affected by the --file option.

unhold
   unhold is used to cancel a previously set hold on a package to allow all actions again.
```

Comment: @AndrewMartin As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"! ;-)